# Google App Engine - Need to use SSL on localhost to develop canvas app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl, reverse-proxy

I'm building an app on a platform that embeds my app into an iframe and passes auth creds via SAML. The platform's dev environment can only load my local app using SSL. It opens https://localhost:8888. I'm building on GAE, but have read that SSL is not supported locally. How can I create a proxy of some type to live at https://localhost:8888 and then redirect the traffic w/ SAML message to my GAE app running locally?

Answer (score 2):

You can use stunnel to achieve this. There are plenty of easily googlable tutorials on how to configure it, so I will not go into that in detail. Make sure you configure a cert that points to your stunnel.pem, and add:

```
[localdev]
accept = 127.0.0.1:8888
connect = 8080
```

This will make stunnel listen for ssl connections on port 8888 and proxy them to 8080, just like you wanted. Then you can use the dev server normally.

Comment: Unfortunately this configuration creates redirect loops.